# Count last 10 rows containing a word

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of wins, "Yes" or "NO" in each cell.  I want to Count the number of "yes" in the last 10 rows.
One issue is that not every row has an answer yet but I want the blank row that has other data to be counted for the last 10.  So I'm using another column that has data as the count reference.  I'm not super formula savvy but have learned a lot lately.  This is the formula I'm trying to use but It does not give me the desired result.

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(M1,COUNT(L:L)-10,0),"Yes")
```

[image: Cell Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OFFSET is Volatile use INDEX(MATCH())

```
MATCH(1E+99,L:L)
```

Will find the last row with a number in it.  Then point that at column M in the index:

```
INDEX(M:M,MATCH(1E+99,L:L))
```

Which now returns the last row in Column M where there is a number in column L

to get the starting cell we subtract 9:

```
INDEX(M:M,MATCH(1E+99,L:L)-9)
```

then it just a mater of treating them like the beginning and end of a range:

```
INDEX(M:M,MATCH(1E+99,L:L)-9):INDEX(M:M,MATCH(1E+99,L:L))
```

Then wrap that in the COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(1E+99,L:L)-9):INDEX(M:M,MATCH(1E+99,L:L)),"Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I wasn't familiar with match and index but this works great!

Comment: What if I only wanted to count the rows that have a "Yes" or "No", omitting blank rows to count the last 10?

Comment: You want to count the last 10 rows but only Yes and No, or you want to count the last 10 rows that are not blank?

Comment: Only the last 10 having yes or no but returning the number of "Yes"

Comment: That is a new question that is beyond the scope of this one.  please choose the one that did what this question is asking and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You're really close! I think you want `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(M1,COUNT(L:L)-1,0,-10),"Yes")`

Row offset: If you have 25 rows of data, `COUNT(L:L)` will give you 25. You want to offset by 24, since we're starting from `M1`, so subtract 1.
Column offset: `0`
Row span: We want to span backwards 10 rows, so `-10`

Source: https://exceljet.net/formula/average-last-5-values

Comment: Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: What if I only wanted to count the rows that have a "Yes" or "No", omitting blank rows to count the last 10?

Comment: As Scott said, that is another question and should be asked in a separate post. I can tell you it will be a bit more complicated, and will involve a conditional on values in column `M` instead of column `L`.